# Error while trying to run Interface in ODI

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-data-integrator

[error that im getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoFQD.png)

I have to start an interface. I have created the topology and the agent. I have started the created Agent, everything works fine. When i have to run the final interface, im getting this error. I have checked all the steps (as instructed in the installation setup manual). Can you please inform me what do i have to check to finish this job ? check the picture above to see the error message

Comment: Please add main error information to the question text, [not by an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).

Comment: I already fixed this error,it was the context name error ...Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SnpContext does not exist`

It looks like the context you passed does not exist in the topology. Also make sure the logical and physical schemas are linked in that context. Same for the agent.

Comment: @eda Could you check that what you are passing is the Context code and not the Context name? Also is the agent attached to the master repository where this context is defined?